# Firebase 9(modular sdk web ) replacement for fieldPath

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the below code with the Firebase SDK 8.

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionName);

var query = collectionRef.where('isFinal', '==', true);

query = query.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', docIds);
return query;
```

I want to replace it code with the modular SDK. So I have written,

```
const dbInstance = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const collectionRef = collection(dbInstance, collectionName);
query(collectionRef, where(???, 'in', docIds));

return query;
```

But somehow I could not find the syntax to get the FieldPath. From the reference, I can read that,

```
/**
 * Returns a special sentinel `FieldPath` to refer to the ID of a document.
 * It can be used in queries to sort or filter by the document ID.
 */
export declare function documentId(): FieldPath;
```

which is imported with

```
import {documentId} from 'firebase/firestore';
```

But when I am using it, it results in an error.

Does anyone know what is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks

**EDIT - 1**
Here is the code I am using to get the documents from firestore

```
//docIds is an array
export const getRecordsByIds = (docIds) => {
  const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let experiences = await getByIds(docIds);
      resolve(experiences);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      reject(error);
    }
  });
  return promise;
};

//Service 
export const getByIds = (docIds) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const documents = await getDocumentWithQuery(
        getByIdQuery(docIds, FirebaseCollection.Experiences)
      );
      if (documents.docs.length > 0) {
        const experiences = await parseExperience(documents.docs);
        resolve(experiences);
      } else {
        reject(docNotExistError);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};

//Query generator
export const getByIdQuery = (docIds, collectionName) => {
  const collectionRef = collection(dbInstance, collectionName);
  console.log(docIds);
  query(collectionRef, where(documentId(), "in", docIds));
  return query;
};



//FirebaseFirestore.web.js
export const getDocumentWithQuery = (query) => {
  const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const documents = await getDocs(query);
      if (documents) {
        resolve(documents);
      } else {
        resolve({});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retrieving documents: ', e);
      reject(e);
    }
  });
  return promise;
};
```

`getRecordsByIds` is the entry point.

Comment: What's the error specifically? `import { documentId } from "firebase/firestore";` seems to work as expected on `9.0.0-beta.6`.

Comment: @samthecodingman It is not an import error. It is about the syntax to pass documentID in query. When I tried `query(collectionRef, where(documentId(), 'in', docIds));` firebase returned 
`"Expected type 'lu', but it was: a function"` error.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I was able to get `Expected type 'gu', but it was: a function"` error. You are actually returning a function. When you `return query`, it returns the query function import here -> `import {query} from "firebase/firestore"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct and is working. Just replace the `???` with `documentId()`. Did you forget the `()` by chance?

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  collection,
  getFirestore,
  query,
  where,
  documentId,
  getDocs,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {...};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const dbInstance = getFirestore();
const collectionRef = collection(dbInstance, "test");

const q = query(collectionRef, where(documentId(), "in", ["test"]));
const querySnap = await getDocs(q);
console.log(querySnap.size);
```

*Firebase JS SDK version: 9.0.0-beta.6*

The problem seems to be here:

```js
export const getByIdQuery = (docIds, collectionName) => {
  const collectionRef = collection(dbInstance, collectionName);
  console.log(docIds);
  query(collectionRef, where(documentId(), "in", docIds));
  
  return query;
  // ^^^ You are returning the "query" function
  // imported from "firebase/firestore"
};
```

Assign the query to a variable and then return it:

```js
export const getByIdQuery = (docIds, collectionName) => {
  const collectionRef = collection(dbInstance, collectionName);
  console.log(docIds);
  const newQuery = query(collectionRef, where(documentId(), "in", docIds));
  return newQuery;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have used the same. But it gives me the error saying that `FirebaseError: Expected type 'lu', but it was: a function`
Please see https://ibb.co/Qp41YNj

Comment: @Harshavardhan can you please share the complete function rather than small snippets? So I can try the exact same code?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have updated the question with the complete function.